# What is a proper Sylow subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, sylow-theory

I am self-studying Abstract algebra from Joseph Gillian and I have this question in Theorem 25.1.

It's image: [image]

> Question: What does the author mean by "proper Sylow Subgroup" in line 3 of proof?

Kindly tell.

Comment: That proof does not use the phrase "proper Sylow sybgroup".

Comment: If $n$ isn't a prime power then no Sylow subgroup is the whole group since Sylow subgroups have prime power order. So every Sylow subgroup is a *proper* subgroup. That's all they're saying.

Answer (score 2):

In set theory, $A$ is said to be a *proper subset* of $B$ if $A$ is a subset of $B$ but it is different from $B$. So $$A \subseteq B \text{ and } A \neq B.$$

In group theory, a subgroup of $G$ is said to be a *Sylow $p$-subgroup* of $G$, if it is the maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$. In other words, if $G$ is a group of order $p^km$, where $p$ does not divide $m$, then a subgroup of order $p^k$ is called a Sylow $p$-subgroup of G.

So, a *proper Sylow subgroup* is both a Sylow subgroup and it is proper.

Comment: And in group theory, which is the topic of the question?

Comment: @Sahiba Arora This is not what I intended to ask, actually wrong question was asked and now I can't delete it as you have asked. So, I am requesting you to delete your answer. I will delete the question after that.